# Symbol table of object files

Tags: compilation, linker, symbols

Im trying to get a hold of the symbol tables for object files. Does anyone know an application which provides this functionality?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know an application which provides this functionality?

The usual UNIX application for looking at the symbol table is `nm`. If you are on an ELF platform, `readelf -Ws foo.o`.

If you are on Windows, use `dumpbin /symbols`.